# Enforcing spaces between tokens in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to build a simple lisp interpreter in Python using pyparsing. I've defined the language:

```
def parse(program):
    _int = pp.Word(pp.nums).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: [int(t[0])])
    _float = pp.Combine(pp.Word(pp.nums) + '.' +
                        pp.Word(pp.nums)).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: [float(t[0])])
    number = _int ^ _float

    extended_chars = "!$%&*+-./:<=>?@^_~"
    symbol = pp.Word(pp.alphas + extended_chars, pp.alphanums + extended_chars)

    atom = number ^ symbol
    _list = pp.Forward()
    _list << pp.nestedExpr(opener="(", closer=")", content=atom)
    exp = atom ^ _list

    return exp.parseString(program, parseAll=True).asList()
```

This is mostly working, but it parses:

```
parse('(1a)') => [[1, 'a']]
```

Which should be interpreted as invalid syntax. I assume this is because the parser doesn't require spaces between tokens in the `nestedExpr`. How do I enforce the spacing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really want to force spaces, shouldn't '1+3' be valid also?

Instead, modify your Word expressions by adding the `asKeyword=True` keyword argument.

As a caution, `nestedExpr` is a very simple-minded parser, and if the contents of the nested expression are to be parsed as well, then you should be using a recursive parser, or possibly infixNotation. See more in this answer: [How do I implement this in ply, given how pyparsing works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864117/how-do-i-implement-this-in-ply-given-how-pyparsing-works/40939346#40939346)